# Function runs but freezes in multiple iterations

Tags: c, r

I have the following function written in C:

```
void across_fip(double *x_a, int *n,  int *d, double *res_a,double *tau,int *epp, double *aux_res, 
double *aux_res2,double *iplus, double *iminus, int *Ts) {
   int i, j, ilow,n_2;
   double ts = (double)(*Ts);
   double temp, crit;
   n_2 = *n;

   for (j=0; j < *d; j++){
      ilow = j * n_2;
      for (i = 0; i < n_2; i++) 
         aux_res[i] = x_a[i+ilow];
      fast_inner_prod(aux_res,n,aux_res2,iplus,iminus);
      for (i = 0; i < n_2; i++){
         temp = fabs(aux_res2[i]);
         crit = tau[j]*ts;
         if (temp >  crit) 
            res_a[i] = res_a[i]+fabs(aux_res2[i]);
      }
   }
}
```

I call this function from R (Rstudio) and then, even though it works, after multiple uses I get the following error message:
"R terminates with error message: This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way".

Is this a memory problem? If yes, how can I fix it?

Comment: You're dereferencing a lot of pointers here. Without seeing the R code they came from, it is hard to know what's wrong.

Comment: Did you make sure `x_a[i+ilow]` never goes out of bounds, and invoke undefined behavior? Same for `aux_res[i]`, `res_a[i]` and `aux_res2[i]`, etc...

Comment: *How* do you load and call this code from R?

Comment: problem solved. Elias was right, the third for loop was going over the limit in certain situations. Thanks.